# PHP PCRE regular expression

Tags: php, regex, latex, non-greedy

In LaTeX, the expression `\o{a}{b}` means the operator 'o' takes two arguments a and b. LaTeX also accepts `\o{a}`, and in this case treats the second argument as the empty string.

Now I try to match the regex `\\\\o\{([\s\S]*?)\}\{([\s\S]*?)\}` against the string `\o{a}\o{a}{b}`. It mistakes the whole string to be a match when it isn't. (The correct interpretation of this string is that the substring `\o{a}{b}` is the only match.) The point is I need to know how to tell PHP to recognise that if there is something else than { following the first }, then it is not a match.

How should I do that?

**Edit**: Arguments of an operator are allowed to contain the symbols `\`, `{` and `}`. But in this case the reason the whole string is not a match is because the curly brackets in `a}\o{a` do not conform to LaTeX rules (e.g. `{` must come before `}`), so that `a}\o{a` cannot be an argument of an operator...

**Edit2**: On the other hand, `\o{{a}}{b}` should be a match as `{a}` is a valid argument.

Comment: 3 answers within 21 seconds of each other.  The regex-ninjas are out in force today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
$s = '\\o{a}\\o{a}{b}';
echo "$s\n";  # Check string
preg_match('~\\\o(\{(?>[^{}\\\]++|(?1)|\\\.)+\}){2}~', $s, $match);
print_r($match);
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/fwiFaP)

The regex:

- uses recursion to deal with nested braces,
- uses backslashes too (`[^{}\\\]` and `\\\.`) to avoid taking literal braces for syntactical braces.

---

```
\\\o             # Matches \o
(                # Recursive group to be
  \{             # Matches {
  (?>            # Begin atomic group (just a group that makes the regex faster)
     [^{}\\\]++  # Any characteres except braces and backslash
  |
     (?1)        # Or recurse the outer group
  |
     \\\.        # Or match an escaped character
  )+             # As many times as necessary
  \}             # Closing brace
){2}             # Repeat twice
```

---

The problem with your current regex is that once this part matched `\\\\o\{([\s\S]*?)`, it will try to look for the next `\}` that is coming, and there, it matters not whether you are using a lazy quantifier or a greedy one. You need to somehow prevent it to match `}` before the actual `\}` comes in the regex.

That's why you have to use `[^{}]` and since you actually can have nested braces inside, that's the ideal situation to use recursion.

Comment: You & Casimir arrived at the right time, he added nesting to the specs... You've got it covered, so pulling out. :) +1

Comment: @zx81 Thanks. LaTeX can be tricky, you could have `\binom{\Large{1}}{\tiny{1}}` for instance, and I always forget the backslashes (using 2 in the negated class didn't work) in PHP. Otherwise, I would have been quicker lol xD But that's ok.

Comment: Good thing you & Caz are on top of it the, I don't know the first thing about LaTeX (not a condom-vending machine???)

Comment: @zx81 Lol, nah, it's math rendering language. You put `\frac{1}{2}` and you get a nice 'half'. `\Sigma` gives the 'summation' symbol, you can get greek characters displayed with `\alpha`, `\beta`, etc. Math language in other words :)

Comment: `Math language in other words` Well, that too will prevent a lot of unwanted pregnancies, so my guess wansn't that far off.

Comment: @Jerry Incidentally, putting `\frac{1}\frac{1}{2}` in actual LaTeX will give an error. But if `\frac` is replaced with `\operatorname`, say (using amsmath package), then it won't...

Comment: @user71815 You mean with the regex or when you try to display that in LaTeX? For the former, I see no issue: [link](http://ideone.com/AJSL0z). And I forgot one more backslash (this omission doesn't have any effect on the regex unless there is a backslash inside the braces).

Comment: @Jerry Ok so I have tested your regex and Casimir's on three examples: `\o{1}\o{1}{1}`, `\o{1}\o{{1}}{{1}}`, `\o{\o{1}}{\o{1}}`. Unfortunately your regex lost to Casimir's on Round 3.

Comment: @Jerry I mean with LaTeX.

Comment: @user71815 Yes, that's because `\frac` requires exactly 2 parameters xD Also yes, I mentioned it in my above comment. On top of Casimir's mine shouldn't break on `\o{\}}` (where the parameter is the literal `}`) but that's just a cosmetic addition I guess.

Comment: @Jerry Your corrected regex beats Casimir on this one. Well done

Comment: @user71815 Thanks! I'm just bummed that you need all those backslash to match a single backslash in PHP... not my language of choice but oh well xD

Answer (score 1):

to deal with possible nested curly brackets you need to use the recursion feature:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
\\o({(?>[^{}]+|(?-1))*}){2}
~x
EOD;
```

where `(?-1)` is a reference to the subpattern of the last capturing group.

Comment: to avoid a catastrophic backtracking if, for example the closing curly bracket is missing.

Comment: Would you explain where it can happen here?

Comment: Make the test yourself, write a test string (with a long first argument an several nested curly brackets to see what happens) and remove the last closing curly bracket. Then compare the number of steps with and without the atomic group.

Comment: You & Jerry arrived at the right time, he added nesting to the specs... You've got it covered, so pulling out. :) +1

Comment: Well, There is no difference in steps at this topic. You just always use atomic grouping as well as possessive quantifiers to make things complicated. *However, you know why!*

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you need to look into using anchors `^` and `$`

```
$pattern = '/^\\o\{.*\}(\{.*\})?$/';
```

I don't know what you consider aceptable values for `a` and `b`, so you can replace `.*` with an appropriate class here.

This allows either `\0{a}` or `\o{a}{b}` formats.  To match only `\o{a}{b}` modify to this:

```
$pattern = '/^\\o\{.*\}\{.*\}$/';
```

Based on your last edit, I would suggest replacing `.*` in above with `[^{]*` as noted in other answers.